# c# Ninject - Unbinding and releasing

Tags: c#, ninject

I am using ninject for with the following code to bind and load the dependencies:

```
kernel.Bind(x =>
   x.FromAssembliesInPath(folder)
      .SelectAllClasses()
      .InheritedFrom<ISample>()
      .BindAllInterfaces()
      .Configure(binding => binding.InSingletonScope()));

var samples = kernel.GetAll<ISample>().ToList();
```

This works fine, and the dependencies are loaded successfullly.

I then have a separate routine to unload the dependencies, and wipe them out completely (delete the files off disk). Here is the code for that:

```
foreach (var s in samples)
{
    s.Dispose();   // ISample Implements IDisposable
}

kernel.Unbind<ISample>();
samples.Clear();
samples = null;

// Delete the folder which contains the ISample assemblies
Directory.Delete(folder, true);
```

The Directory.Delete() causes an UnauthorizedAccessException (Access to the path is denied.)

I must be missing a step that fully releases the dynamically loaded assemblies. I need help to identify what that step is, and what additional code is required to fully release the referenced assemblies so that they can be safely removed from disk.

Comment: You can't unload individual assemblies in .NET once they have been loaded. Do you know if Ninject is creating a separate AppDomain to load them in and then unloading the entire thing? Somehow I doubt it would be.

Comment: As @MattiVirkkunen comments. But I'd expand that if you are looking to do this I would have a look at [Microsoft Add-In](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) especially around `MAF` as this will allow you to load assemblies into a separate `AppDomain` which can then be unloaded during runtime.

Comment: So is the answer that this is not possible to do with Ninject?

Comment: I'd say yes it is possible but I wouldn't believe that Ninject would load the assembly in a different `AppDomain`. So you could manually scan that folder, load the assemblies into a separate `AppDomain`, add the `ISample` interfaces into your Ninject container and when time comes do an `AppDomain.Unload`. But it'd be a very manual process and isn't quite as simple as your 1 liner for Ninject.

Comment: But within the same AppDomain is simply not possible.. ?

Comment: No I would say using the same AppDomain would make what you are attempting to do impossible. To be able to unload the assemblies you would need to unload the `AppDomain` effectively killing your application.

Comment: To reiterate what I said earlier, you cannot unload individual assemblies, you can only unload entire AppDomains. So in order to unload some assemblies without killing your entire program, you need to load them into a separate one that you can then unload without affecting your original AppDomain.

Comment: Can you update your question with your extra information so that it can be seen. Also can you expand on the "If I change the location of the folder so that it somewhere else" part as I'm unsure what you mean, are you moving the assemblies or just trying to delete a different folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not a limitation of Ninject, but a limitation of .NET. You can't unload assemblies from an AppDomain. The AppDomain will always keep the loaded assemblies referenced, and you can't delete the files from disk until the AppDomain is unloaded.

So what you should do is spin up a second AppDomain from within the main app and load the assemblies from there. When you're done, you can unload the AppDomain from the main domain and after that you can delete the files.

Comment: @David: I can't confirm what you see, just what I know and that is: "you can't unload an assembly." That doesn't mean that there are always ways to force overwriting a lock that a process has on a file using the Windows API. Tools like Sysinternals use this. It might crash the process though.